# How to setup Emacspeak on raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, packages, text-to-speech

I want to setup emacspeek package on raspi. text to speech reader usable for blind users. But currently emacspeek is available only on archlinux.How to make it working on raspbian?

```
sudo apt-get install emacspeak
```

was able to install the package after which there is some configuration that needs to be done.How to make espeak up and running

Comment: I can't find where anyone has gotten this working on Raspbian yet, but these guys seem to have created an Arch Linux based distro which includes emacspeak http://raspberryvi.org/wiki/doku.php/home.

Answer (score 2):

It's now part of the standard raspbian distribution:

```
$ apt-cache search emacspeak
eflite - Festival-Lite based emacspeak speech server
emacspeak - speech output interface to Emacs
yasr - General-purpose console screen reader
```